# Best US based credit card payments solution with PHP APIs

Tags: php, payment-gateway, payment-processing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Credit card payment gateway in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439904/credit-card-payment-gateway-in-php)

I am looking for a solid credit card solution and we are not interested in PayPal. I am currently unsure about the volume of transactions. Someone suggested merchantone but after looking at some reviews i have my apprehensions. Idealling something around a ~2% transaction charge, with some monthly fees.

What do you guys suggest, we need a flexible API which we can utilize easily with PHP. Any recommendations will be helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439904/credit-card-payment-gateway-in-php ; see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556/whats-the-best-online-payment-processing-solution

Comment: It might be a dupe but I am looking for some more information, and hoping to get more input the the previous guy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Authorize.Net payment gateway](http://www.authorize.net/) API is by far the easiest to use. They provide [sample code](http://developer.authorize.net/samplecode/) and there are good classes and tutorials out there, too.

To use Authorize.Net you would need a separate merchant account. There are lots of providers out there and their rates and fees will vary. But all of them work with Authorize.Net. Your merchant account provider can set you up with them or you can choose from any of their resellers to get an account.

Comment: Yes, this is where i am really confused, so to utilize Authorize.net i need to find some provider (like merchantone) .. cant we deal with authorize.net directly and bypass the middle man? If we have to utilize the middle man, then which ones are recommended. I would really appreciate your input.

Comment: Authorize.Net doesn't offer merchant accounts so you do need to find a provider on your own. Their resellers tend to be merchant account providers since they the two services go hand in hand. It's hard to recommend a merchant account provider since their rates keep changing and that's what really matters. I would say call some of their resellers and get rates and fees. Choose the one whose rates where good and they seemed knowledgeable about everything. If they sound shady or not to sure of themselves that's a sign you need to move on.

Answer (score 1):

I've done custom integrations with PayPal's PayFlow pro, Firstdata (used to be LinkPoint), and authorize.net... and would have to say authorize.net was by far the best to work with. Their API is heaps less complicated than FirstData's (in my opinion), and they generally have better support.

Answer (score 0):

How about Authorize.net?

http://www.authorize.net/

Comment: Actually i am a bit confused about Authorize.net and what would be involved in getting an account and the fees, cause it seems they more reseller oriented?

Answer (score 0):

Or google checkout?

http://checkout.google.com