# Payment system - distribute money between user and site admin

Tags: php, payment

We have advertisers module where advertisers can place ads in to the site. 
When user clicks ad, system should automatically sends money to site admin account and users account.

Notes: 
. Assume each ad cost $10, need to distribute $5 each. 
. Assume system has user and site admin credit/debit cards info.

**My questions**
1) How can I achieve it? 
2) I want to achieve it through php. is there any issues?

Thanks
Venu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either Express Checkout Parallel payments to send $5 to each recipient's PayPal account, or PayPal Adaptive Chained / Parallel payments. The difference is that Express Checkout doesn't offer chained payments.
You cannot, however, automatically transfer these funds from a PayPal account to a credit card and/or bank account.

Have a look at https://www.x.com/ for documentation (I can't post more than two links..).

Comment: Thanks to your prompt reply. I want a way to send money to credit card/debit card. Is it possible through authorize.net at least?

Comment: But Client don't want to force the users to have Paypal Account.

Comment: I got answer for this through another question.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754863/credit-card-crediting-and-debiting-ach-crediting-and-debiting-through-api-witho

Answer (score 1):

1. You will have to use some payment gateway to actually "post" a financial transaction. [Paypal](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_download_sdks), or [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439904/credit-card-payment-gateway-in-php);
2. Php is way mature now, and I believe you [can do that](http://phpfour.com/blog/2009/02/php-payment-gateway-library-for-paypal-authorizenet-and-2checkout/) in php.

Comment: Yes I have worked on paypal. By question is can I transfer an amount from merchant payal account to credit card using paypal api?

Comment: You can to transfer *from* merchant account, **to** credit card??

Answer (score 0):

You can do this through Authorize.net with minimal coding skills.