# Credit card crediting and debiting / ACH crediting and debiting through Api without user interaction

Tags: api, e-commerce, payment, credit-card, authorize.net

I'm looking for a way to automate a transfer from one credit card to another credit card or from one bank account to another bank account, without the end user having to login to something like paypal or amazon payments to complete the process (by transferring their on-line balance to their bank account).

This is extension to the earlier question.
[API For Direct Deposit (ACH, EFT, Whatever)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679946/api-for-direct-deposit-ach-eft-whatever)

Anybody solved this. Could you suggest the answer?

**[EDIT]**
I know that PCI compliant issues will be there to store credit card info in database. So I am checking for an API which saves saves the info and doing crediting and debiting credit card.

Is there any issue to store the bank info in database?

**[new]**
I saw that there is an api for that. echeck.net which uses ACH network and credit/debits a bank account.

Is it possible to store the bank info in authorize.net server through CIM API, and use them whenever website needs to collect money from consumer, through a script? and through script is it possible to credit the users bank account from website bank account?

Comment: Most banks charge for such services, from what I know. Why not use a proven standard like PayPal or something?

Comment: We want a system which does the money transfer from the site bank account/credit card to user bank account/credit card automatically instead of sending out the checks manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I saw that there is an api for that.
>   echeck.net which uses ACH network and
>   credit/debits a bank account.
>
> Is it possible to store the bank info
>   in authorize.net server through CIM
>   API, and use them whenever website
>   needs to collect money from consumer,
>   through a script? and through script
>   is it possible to credit the users
>   bank account from website bank
>   account?

CIM does work with eChecks and should do what you need. See page 9 of the [CIM manual](http://www.authorize.net/support/CIM_XML_guide.pdf) for details of the `createCustomerProfileRequest` API call.

Comment: Thanks to your reply. I heard that, we can debit the money but not credit. is it true?

Comment: I believe you can only debit transaction that were processed within the last 120 days and the amount can't be larger then what was processed. In other words you can't use this system as a money transferring system.

Comment: ok is there any payment gateway or API which serves my requirements? any solutions to it? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I have spoke to authorize.net guys, They sent an email as below......

We want to confirm that through CIM API you can use the Profile ID for future transactions, regardless what the amount is that you need to charge the customer. Unlike, the Automated Recurring Billing (ARB) service, you do not need a fixed amount set for charging the customer, nor are CIM payments scheduled. You can use CIM to charge the customer, whenever you need to.

Comment: @Venu have you solved your problem. If yes, how you did this. I've same requirements