# Transfer fund from a merchant account to a credit/debit card holder bank, probably using ACH

Tags: paypal, authorize.net, marketplace, braintree, balanced-payments

My problem is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754863/credit-card-crediting-and-debiting-ach-crediting-and-debiting-through-api-with)

How i can credit my customer from their online balance deposited by them on our website.

We are using Braintree API. It has marketplace services too. But escrow is not what i'm looking for. I want to know whether Braintree API/ PayPal ACH API is capable of crediting our customer.

How about [Balanced](https://www.balancedpayments.com/) API. Can this solve my problem?

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, Balanced can do what you're looking for: https://www.balancedpayments.com/payouts

Comment: Braintree has an option to transfer to user local bank. They call it Detaiched Credits https://support.braintreepayments.com/customer/portal/articles/1080608-refunds-voids-detached-creditshttp:#Credits

Comment: I work at Braintree. It sounds like detached credits aren't what you're looking for -- maybe [marketplace](https://www.braintreepayments.com/features/marketplace) or [Venmo Payouts](https://venmo.com/payouts)?

Comment: Is Venmo Payouts works for Canadian Business? Who is behind Venmo? How safe is this?

Comment: @agf, How braintree marketplace can be used to transfer some funds to our customer bank account?

Answer (score 1):

To transfer funds to user local bank account, you can use Braintree's [Detached Credit Feature](https://support.braintreepayments.com/customer/portal/articles/1080608-refunds-voids-detached-creditshttp:#Credits).
But, the biggest problem is that in order to use this feature you must request send a request to have this capability enabled via an email to Braintree; at this point they will enable it temporarily. Once the transaction is completed, they disable it within 24 hours, at most.